# Jquery click doesn't open new window

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

First of all I am using the Codeigniter Framework. I have put my jquery.js in the same directory as home.php. My controller would load the home view. And below is what my home view looks like. As you can see I am trying to open google.com in a new window when I click the td with the id of more_info. But it does not work. Why?

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#more_info").click(function(){
  window.open("google.com");
  return false;
});
</script>

<?php foreach ($records as $row) : ?>

    <table border="1">

        <tr>
            <td id="more_info">More Info</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for any errors?

Comment: You can only use an id once in a page.  Change the id to a class and change the selector to `$(".more_info")`

Comment: You should only have 1 id since this is in a loop you are going to wind up with duplicate ids. Changes these to classes. You should also pass the events object to the callback function and call preventDefault() instead of return false.

Comment: @Archer and johnferrie, I am gonna append the more_info with the product id later on.

Comment: It won't work until you do.  Different browser behave differently when confronted with multiple elements with the same ID, so you should just not do it from the start, otherwise you're introducing problems :)

Comment: @Archer I tried change to class selector, used div, but it still does not response. Even the alert() does not respond

Comment: I found out what the problem is. Apparently when using CodeIgniter (I'm new) the directory of the jquery.js file should be put another directory unlike in the normal way (not Codeigniter) I just put it in the same directory as the page I am working on and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript is executed as soon as it loads, which is before that element loads.  So when the JavaScript code runs it's trying to attach a click event handler to an element which doesn't exist yet.

You can wait for the elements to load by wrapping your JavaScript code with the document's ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#more_info").click(function(){
        window.open("google.com");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Or, a shorter version:

```
$(function () {
    $("#more_info").click(function(){
        window.open("google.com");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've updated my question with a picture. Wonder if the location of the script file is correct.

Comment: @LimGuangJian: That image implies to me that the directory structure of the project is not the actual routes being served by the application.  This is commonly the case with any MVC web application.  You can't put the JavaScript files in the `Views` directory because that's not where they're being served from.  You'd have to put them in a directory that's served as regular content, not as code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your script you have written should be after the page is done. (you
   should put your script after the php code).
2. Your code is wrong.

   2.1 Loop is not compilable. For an example choose one table + one column.

   2.2 You also need to refer to googleapi in order using jquery.

   2.3 You should refer to http://google.com, and not google.com (which obviously open a page named google.com on your site, and I persume
   this is not what you meant.

Good luck.

Comment: I found out what the problem is. Apparently when using CodeIgniter (I'm new) the directory of the jquery.js file should be put another directory unlike in the normal way (not Codeigniter) I just put it in the same directory as the page I am working on and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, I put my code, which work for me.

Pay attention the ***script tag*** is after at the end of html (after all elements are created properely).

Good luck!!!

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td id="more_info">More Info</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#more_info").click(function(){
  window.open("http://google.com");
  return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using same  id of td, so you should use the class instead of repeating id

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".more_info").click(function(){
  window.open("google.com");
  return false;
});
</script>

<?php foreach ($records as $row) : ?>

    <table border="1">

        <tr>
            <td class="more_info">More Info</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```